# How to take out all duplicated files in subfolders from a huge set of files/subfolders in shortest time span?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, file-management

**Situation:** I have build up an application in JAVA that runs over a LAN on a PC that we use as a server. This PC is dedicated to this application and has a fairly good configuration (core-i 7 with 8 GB RAM). 
My app is aimed to :

- Store data for a huge file manipulation project (around 12 million files 200 KB each) in its database (MySQL).
- Server PC acts as a database server also, and nearly 20 pc's, interacts with database all the day long.
- Project process is consists of multiple stages. For each stage there are separate folders, that this software moves the files to over network on a separate storage server of size 16 TB.
- The network cable between server PC and storage server is a GIGA cable while the other network cables are normal ones.
- In this process everyday up to 60,000 new files are generated, and 100,000 records are inserted in the database and at the end of the day my app sends a mail report to the client.

**Problem:** Our client has asked us to provide a mechanism to identify files with the same name, and submit them in seperately. I can not rely on the database records, since over different stages, users delete or modify the files. Also from the other hand I need to think about the time. The process of duplicate check is to be done everyday before sending the report. 
My prefered solution is to use a Java and/or MySQL based solution. I tried:

- Searching and indexing all files from storage server, but I changed my mind when the program was running for three hours and was still going on.
- Also database is to accept the duplicate names, so I can not put unique constraint on it, I can not make another column as file count and put a unique constraint on file names, since it slows down data enteries (they use insert batch). I do not want to create another table to keep the unique file names for this purpose only, since it is redundency.
- Mutli tasking tried.

**Question:** What is the best solution in Java/MySQL to check for files with the same name over huge amount of files/folders, over a busy network in minimum amount of time, considering in mind that already entered database records are not accurate?

Comment: Are your machines/servers all Linux or Windows?

Comment: Our machines are all windows.

Comment: Do you mean files with duplicated names? Or files with duplicated content?I mean you could have two files called `fred` in different folders with totally different content, is that what you want to identify? Or you could have two files called `a` and `b` that both contain the same PowerPoint presentation.

Comment: Have you set some limits to the number of files in each directory. Windows gets horribly slow with too many files in a directory? Also, have you lumped all your disks together in one massive RAID on your storage server, or split your filesystem up into indepenedent chunks to improve performance?

Comment: Files are spread in folders of 300 to 350 files. Size of each file is limited to 100 kb to 400 kb. Each file has a name of 9 chars, and the first two chars of all files in each folder is the same. It is possible that two different files with different contents have the same exact name and ".JPG" extension. Making an indexing table in database is a suggestion by team. 
Also all the files is on one single RAID on storage server.

Comment: If "already entered database records are not accurate", then why do you even keep them? Why do you generate reports out of inaccurate data? If inaccurate report of what files are in the DB is good enough for your client, then why just as inaccurate report on duplicate filenames is not good enough?

Comment: Although the issue is so old, but anyway the matter was that inaccurate was better than nothing, still they used to put us uder pressure for the same

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation before, well, not of de-duplication, but of categorization. Not many ready-made tools are available that are free and open-source and that can take the information to a database. But, after a long hunt, I did find one great useful tool, DirectoryListPrint.

http://download.cnet.com/Directory-List-Print-Pro/3000-2248_4-10911895.html

The last I saw, they had a free version that can dump the data into a CSV-like format in their own window or as a CSV file. From there, take it on to a simple database like Access or SQL Server or something, then run a query to find duplicate files. If you have to do this repetitively, use an automation tool such as AutoIt or AutoHotKeys to automate the task.

Comment: Also, making an additional table in the database is something you should not rule out. May be you could create that, but have a routine for management of the that table's size or the temporary nature of such table.